# Append new properties to existing JSON object

Tags: javascript

I have the following json

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"company","op":"cn","data":"School"}]}
```

I want to inject new properties into every item in the rules array to get something like this.

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"company","op":"cn","data":"School", "dataType": "Organization", "dataProperty": "name"}]}
```

The plan is to loop through the array called rules and dynamically add the correct values using the following.

```
var filters = $.parseJSON(postData.filters); 
var rules = filters.rules;
for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) { 
  rules[i]
}
```

I have access to rules at index "i". I tried `rules[0].push({dataType: "Organization"});` 
please help.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object."](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: So, is `rules[i]` going to be a single object like `{"dataType": "Organization"}` or an array of such objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var filters = $.parseJSON(postData.filters); 
var rules = filters.rules;
for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) { 
  rules[i].dataType = "Organization";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`rules[i]` is an object, not an array, so there is no `push` method to call. Use [property assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators).

```
// ...
rules[i].dataType = "Organization";
// ...
```

Comment: Scooped me while my mouse was moving to the button!